# Like GWT ListBox.setVisibleItemCount(), Is there any API available in SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, listbox, smartgwt

To set number of visible Items in GWT **ListBox** we have ListBox.setVisibleItemCount() API but I didn't find any way to achieve the same in SmartGWT's **SelectItem**. My requirement is to display an image and text in SelectItem list and like in GWT we should be able to display multiple items at a time.

There is an option to set mutiselect using selectItem.setMultiple(true); and 
 selectItem.setMultipleAppearance(MultipleAppearance.GRID);  but if we set multiselect in this way, image is not displaying in the list box only text is coming.

I am not getting whether displaying multiple items is possible in SmartGWT's **SelectItem** (with image) or not, or Am i missing something here.

Comment: If the description is not clear enough please ask, I will update.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. Here is the example from the official SmartGWT showcase.

```
final SelectItem selectItemWithIcons = new SelectItem();  
        selectItemWithIcons.setMultiple(true);  
        selectItemWithIcons.setTitle("Select");  
        selectItemWithIcons.setHint("<nobr>Multi Select with icons</nobr>");  
        selectItemWithIcons.setValueMap(valueMap);  
        selectItemWithIcons.setImageURLPrefix("flags/16/");  
        selectItemWithIcons.setImageURLSuffix(".png");  
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> valueIcons = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();  

        valueIcons.put("US", "US");  
        valueIcons.put("CH", "CH");  
        valueIcons.put("JA", "JA");  
        valueIcons.put("IN", "IN");  
        valueIcons.put("GM", "GM");  
        valueIcons.put("FR", "FR");  
        valueIcons.put("IT", "IT");  
        valueIcons.put("RS", "RS");  
        valueIcons.put("BR", "BR");  
        valueIcons.put("CA", "CA");  
        valueIcons.put("MX", "MX");  
        valueIcons.put("SP", "SP");  
        selectItemWithIcons.setValueIcons(valueIcons);
```

If you have some images called US.png, CH.png, etc, at GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + /flags/16/ this should work.

https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#multi_select_combobox_category